# Is there any media query for non-retina display?

Tags: css, retina

According to [an article on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/), the future proof media queries for retina display can be wrote as:

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 

  /* Retina-specific stuff here */

}
```

What if I want to write CSS codes for non-retina display?

I know you can write some CSS codes for non-retina display first, and then overwrite it for retina display with the above media queries. But is there any media query which is specifically for non-retina display?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/), also on CSS-Tricks, states that you can reverse the logic with not. So in theory:

```
@media
not screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
not screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
not screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
not screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
not screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
not screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 

  /* non-Retina-specific stuff here */

}
```