# Add content to an anchor link on hover with transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would like to know how i can archive that an icon appears on hovering a anchor link on the page.

I started a little snippet which I thought might do my expected behavior, but instead it leaves a gap. The text should extend (grow) on size as you hover over the anchor.

How can I archive this?

```css
a:after {
    content:" ";
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
    transition: all 250ms;
}
a:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
    transition: all 250ms;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Test</a>. And I would like to link you on <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Stackoverflow</a> if you have any questions.</p>
```

Comment: Another side question.. Is my approach, fading in from -20px to 0px, still valid nowadays or are there better solutions. I saw people also do `ease-in`.

Comment: What do you expect it to do, push the text to the side on hover?

Comment: Yes sir, exactly. The text should not contain any gaps (or icons) in general, but if you hover over an anchor there should spawn an icon next to the anchor and push the text to the side.

Comment: See my answer below, I think I have your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative `margin-left: -20px;` to pull the gap backward whilst there is no hover. Then when the user hovers over the text, you can make `margin-left: 0;` to add the gap back in for the icon to fit.

```css
a:after {
    content:" ";
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
    transition: all 250ms;
}
a:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    margin-left:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
    transition: all 250ms;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Test</a>. And I would like to link you on <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Stackoverflow</a> if you have any questions.</p>
```

**Edit:** OP - If you use `-26px`, this is what happens. The full stop/period gets pushed into the letter `t`. This is because the gap that is added is only `20px` wide so, therefore, you only need subtract `20px`. [image]

Comment: Aha, cool, that makes sense indeed. So `margin-left` does the trick i was looking for, Thank you sir. I was thinking of kinda the same behavior, and wondered why `left` wasn't working.

Comment: Adjusted your answer to `margin-left:-26px;`, which makes the text more narrow if it is not hovered.

Comment: You have a 20px gap that usually wouldn't be there so we only take off 20px. Now that it is 26px, the full stop is now conflicting inside the 'test' text. 

By using -26px, you are taking off more space than what would be there if you didn't have an icon. There is now less space than a normal space...

Comment: Yep I see. Tested in different Browser in `IE Edge 38.14393.1066.0` it seems to be `-20px`, in `Firefox 55.0.3` and `Chrome 60.0.3112.113` `-20px` leaves small gaps, which are solved at `-26px`. So this approach is not 100% cross-browser compatible, but solves at least my expected result. If you have an idea how to solve this too, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: I would take screenshots and post it as a new question, my friend :-)

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to be an issue with emojis and how browsers renders them actually, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42016125. SInce my snippet just was a test case, I know I can prevent this by using an icon or font-ligature with a width that is consistent. Anyhow it was good we fall over this minor detail :-P. Thanks again.