# Apple emojis are overlapped in readme.md file

Tags: github, markdown, emoji, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I was using emoji in my Github profile readme file. There I placed three emojis side by side. Like the following:

```
I would like to introduce myself as a self-taught  **Frontend Software Engineer**
```

Now when I visit the readme from Mac, **these emojis are overlapped. But in the Windows OS**, it's working fine.

#### In the Mac:

[image]

#### In the Windows:

[image]

### Can anybody tell me what's the reason behind that? And what's the workaround for this problem? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It might be helpful to say what browser you are using

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? On Stack Overflow, reading this on a Mac using Safari, Firefox, and Brave, the problem doesn't reproduce on this page in your code block. That suggests that something in the MD rendering engine may be involved, or in the browser's text layout engine. Are you using the same browser on both platforms? (I will say that the emoji are slightly closer in Firefox than in Brave or Safari, but not overlapping
.)

Comment: Reproduced. This only happens on Brave for me, and not Firefox or Safari, so I assume it's a Chrome issue. https://github.com/rnapier/rnapier

Comment: Found it. Known Chrome bug when using a non-Retina screen on a Mac. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596223) and duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016125/emoji-rendered-in-chrome-have-different-widths-than-in-other-browsers I can reproduce this on an old external monitor, but it doesn't reproduce on my laptop's monitor.

Comment: I found this problem in Chrome on mac.

Comment: @RobNapier
Here's the link https://github.com/Showrin. You can find them in the readme.md file.

Comment: Yep, this looks exactly like the Chrome-non-retina bug. I don't know any way to fix this via rendered Markdown until Chrome fixes their bug. You can fix it with your own style sheets as describe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145771/97337 but I don't believe you can apply a style sheet to GitHub pages.

Comment: Tried brother. But github don't support them :( @RobNapier

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious workaround is just to space out the emojis ie

```markdown
I would like to introduce myself as a self-taught  **Frontend Software Engineer**
```

and it will look like this on Windows-Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I did that but in the windows they more empty space which doesn't look so good. :(

Comment: I think it looks ok, my markdown editor actually does spaces after emojis automatically so take that as you will