# Unicode emoji letter spacing issue

Tags: css, text, emoji, overlapping

I have an issue showing text with emojis. You can see that the "Test" after the emoji is overlapping the emoji. In search of a CSS that breaks this, I have deleted everything using the inspector but the issue is still visible.

[image]

The same code in a simple local HTML file is rendering fine as you can see in the second picture.
Is my "localhost" tab still caching some styling or is the issue somewhere else.

[image]

The above issue is visible on my external monitor.

If I move the window to my Mac screen it is rendered a bit differently!
The "localhost" version is rendered fine but the local HTML file version has a spacing between the emoji and the text after it.

[image]
[image]

I have some errors reported by the inspector but this should not impact this simple code in the "localhost" version.
Something strange is going on here and I can't figure out why so if somebody had this issue before and has solved it I'd be very thankful for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug, there are little tricks to fix it

Trick 1 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145771/16547877

Trick 2 : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1083965#c4

Comment: The only issue with adding a margin with media query is that my emoji is not wrapped with an element I can target.
But yes... it definitely looks like a bug.
Thanks for the links.